# PHP Curl get specific data json

Tags: php, json, curl

I have `PHP Curl` to get data information cost of shipping.

```
$('#kurir').change(function()
{
    var asal = $('#asal').val();
    var kab = $('#kabupaten').val();
    var kurir = $('#kurir').val();
    var berat = $('#berat').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'cek_ongkir.php',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data :  {'kab_id' : kab, 'kurir' : kurir, 'asal' : asal, 'berat' : berat},
        success: function (jsonStr) {

        alert(jsonStr.rajaongkir.city_name);

            $("#service").text(jsonStr);
        }
    });
});
```

and the result of JSON is

[image]

My question is how can I get `city_name` from that JSON code?

**UPDATE**

Got undefined when try to get `jsonStr.rajaongkir.results.costs`

[image]

Comment: jsonStr.rajaongkir.destination_details.city_name   you ill get name

Comment: seriously, did you try something before posting here ? if you know about ajax, this shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 2):

try to alert :

```
jsonStr.rajaongkir.destination_details.city_name
```

Comment: Hi @Sachin, please see my updated post. I got undefined when trying to alert `jsonStr.rajaongkir.results.costs`

Comment: Because it is in Array